# Curbing spammy and often downright disgusting "NSFW"/indecent questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

Unfortunately, being designated as a health discussion forum will inevitably attract distasteful and sometimes disingenuous trolls asking NSFW questions (for those who have no idea what "NSFW" means, it's loosely defined as "anything that will incur an indecency-related fine from the FCC or similar communications authority if you broadcast it on radio or TV during most hours"

Suggestion: add an "nsfw" tag and require indecent questions to use it. Failure to apply nsfw tag -> massive downvotes/reports and quick moderator edits to add the nsfw tag; repeated offenses (when it becomes clear that someone outright refuses to comply with the nsfw tagging requirements) incur temporary bans. Add an option to automatically hide or ignore "nsfw" content.

Comment: Could you link example questions that would fall under this criteria? Being in a quite liberal country, I don’t know any question I‘ve ever seen on Health that wouldn’t be broadcasted on TV/Radio and my expertise in American communication authorities is quite limited. That would help my understanding of how this is supposed to work.

Comment: OMG, that's not what NSFW means at all. "Not safe for work" means any unfortunate content you wouldn't want popping up on your screen inadvertently while browsing the web or email in a professional setting (i.e. work).

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this is a flat-out no because it's a meta-tag and provides no meaningful information to what the question is *about* whatsoever. We don't allow tags like that. But let's also dive into your reasoning here a bit, because it's very off-base and doesn't really come close to solving the problem you identified.

You identify trolls as the ones causing this problem, which likely means they're asking poor questions that need to be closed and deleted quickly. But alas, trolls often intentionally do things *to irk people*, and I don't know how you expect anyone like that to ever use a NSFW tag. That would kind of defeat the purpose of trolling - it's not exactly fun for them if they go warning people first.

So... you downvote everyone who doesn't use the tag appropriately? **Bad idea.** You can't expect every new visitor to the site to know the intricate details of the site, especially not that the need to add a NSFW tag in a variety of scenarios. Then you're just downvoting newcomers for not knowing a... pretty dumb rule. That's not very welcoming at all. Besides, if a question really is trolling, it's going to attract downvotes, and close votes, and delete votes on its own. So the the "lack of tag should trigger downvotes" ideology there is kind of pointless. You're telling people to do what they would have already done in that situation.

Further to that point: you want this tag added so you know what not to look at while you're at work. But if someone forgets to add it and you end up looking at the question, **you already saw it**. So what exactly does downvoting do for you? You can't undo opening the page just because someone forgot to add a tag, or a troll posted something intentionally NSFW to annoy you. You're still gonna see stuff that you probably didn't want to see at work regardless of this tag.

So, just use your judgement. You get a title and short blurb of text when viewing the questions list. If it looks anything remotely like it wouldn't be appropriate at work, don't open it. But nothing you do is going to prevent *all* the situations, and NSFW content isn't all that much different than spammers posting inappropriate images, or trolls we've had in the past posting pornographic content (like some *really* disgusting stuff). **If you're having consistent problems with content you shouldn't be opening at work, maybe just don't use this particular site at work.** It's a *health* site of all things - you're going to occasionally see or read gross things even from users with good intentions.

Comment: +1: this is what I would have reasoned as well. Good questions are allowed (and one could ignore certain tags), but we don’t need a meta tag as an excuse for bad question.